# "Unable to install GRUB in /dev/sda" when trying to install Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: grub2, system-installation

I have a ThinkPad T520, and I want to install Ubuntu 16.04 on it. It originally had Windows 10 on it, I attempted to install ubuntu alongside Windows 10, but it failed with the error "Unable to install GRUB in /dev/sda". I then decided I didn't want Windows 10 and decided to just install ubuntu. I received the same error. I'm not even sure if I have the correct UEFI settings to install a new OS. The laptop has an mSATA SSD as /dev/sda and an HDD as /dev/sdb .

The output from `sudo lshw -short` and `sudo lshw -class disk -class storage` is here https://pastebin.com/34Zgpxac

After I get the warning I get a window "Bootloader install failed" with 3 options to pick from: "Choose a different device to install the bootloader on", "Continue without a bootloader", "Cancel the installation", but when I select an option and click "OK" the window stays up and doesn't do anything.

I understand there's already a lot of posts on this topic but there's so much information to read through that it's overwhelming and I just want to get my computer working ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to disable quick boot in the BIOS settings. I disabled quick boot and then the installation worked.

edit: it might also be because I installed the OS on the HDD rather than the mSATA SSD.

edit: it was entirely because I had not disabled quick boot